# Breakpoints not hit while debugging an asp.net web application using local iis server (7.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Breakpoints are not being hit while using the local IIS server. It works perfectly with the visual studio's inbuilt debugging server. I've added the website to the IIS and started it. Every time it shows 'No Symbols have been loaded for this document.' Pls help.

With regards,
JosephJCKochi

Comment: Can you confirm that you didn't add a `RELEASE` build (without .pdb)? How did you add this website to IIS? Could you add the `<WebProjectProperties>` section of your .csproj project file?

Comment: I've browsed the published folder in the IIS and added it.

Comment: You should rather switch between VS builtin server and local IIS by modifying the project properties to make this work.

Comment: Yes I've modified that already.